# Translating song lyrics: SHE Starlight 2 verses

Tags: translation, lyrics

I'm working on translating song lyrics, and trying to understand the meaning behind the song 星光 by S.H.E.

The lyrics I'm struggling with are:

也許是你笑的弧度和我很像

Translation guess: Perhaps its the shape of your smile [that] I really like(像??).

and later:

才會背靠著背一起等天亮

Translation guess: Until then we lie side by side waiting for dawn.

Comment: re 1st line:弧度 radian (angle measure unit),used in 嘴角的弧度 to
measure facial expressions cf.看恋人嘴角的弧度 从笑容解读恋人性格 http://scitech.people.com.cn/GB/53754/4296997.html
2nd line: back leaning against back waiting for daybreak

Comment: I can find translations for the literal definition of each word, but it doesn't make sense to me. I'll add my best guess at translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Missing or omitted**:

Line 1: "也許是你笑的弧度和我(的)很像 "

**the possessive marker 的 is omitted,

我= I /  我的 (with object)= my / 我的 (without object)= **mine**

Line 2: "(我們)才會背靠著背一起等天光"

** The subject pronoun "我們"(us) is omitted, 
In Chinese, we omit pronoun whenever possible.

**Break down**:

[1.也許是] [2. 你笑的弧度] [3. 和我(的)很像]

[1.may be it is because] [2. the curvature of your (mouth) (when you) smile] [3.is very similar to mine ]

** they simile like each other, imply their personalities are similar too.

[4.(我們) 才會] [5.背靠著背] [6.一起] [7.等天光]

[4. that made us] [ 5.back pressing against each others back] [6.together] [7.waiting for dawn]

** It is a graphic description of a couple sit closely together in darkness and just let time pass. (supposedly a romantic scene.)

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down and providing a descriptive answer!